# Rails and Sinatra - Not getting any response from Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku

I am attempting to read from a postgresql database hosted on Heroku using a web interface developed using Sinatra and Rails. The site is functioning properly and upon sending a post request, the site returns no values from the table I'm reading from. No errors occurred.

**My site.rb**

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'sinatra/activerecord'
require_relative 'app/models/admin_user'

set :database_file, 'config/database.yml'

get '/' do
  erb :index
end

post '/login' do
  @result = AdminUser.take(10)
  @result.to_s
end
```

The response I get when I post to `/login` is just this:

```
[#]
```

The same database.yml file was used for another mobile backend project and the endpoints were able to establish the connection. In this case, no errors are produced so I'm assuming the database was connected successfully? How can I resolve this?

Comment: restart your Heroku server using this command - heroku restart --a app_name

Comment: @AniketShivamTiwari Thanks but it didn't fix it either. Could it be an issue in the database config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the code is correct and the database connection was being established. I just wasn't converting the response to json. Silly but I am just learning ruby on rails. Going to post this here to help out any other person:

```
post '/login' do
  @result = AdminUser.take(10)
  @result.to_json
end
```